# receiving 403 forbidden when attempting to validate json Bearer header through spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

So I have a few modules.
I have a discovery service module, a client module to connect to the discovery service and i also have a zuul gateway module.

the client and zuul module both have their own instances of spring security.

the client module has a h2 in memory database that it depends on and when creating a new user the user has all its information stored inside the database.

i am also using postman.
i have a few methods i use in postman.

1. create a new user:  < - works great

   (this http request calls a controller bean i have created in my user module that creates a user entity with username password etc and stores it into the h2 database)
2. user login:  < - works great

(this postman http request to /login will trigger spring security to attempt to login. it does this by taking in email and password from the http request in json format. and then returns in the header to postman a token created by authenticationManager)

3. check user status:  < - works not so great
   (this is where the problem starts. this is calling users/check which is access controlled by my zuul gateway. i can put my ide into debug mode and watch as i pass the token from postman into the authentication manager. its receiving the token and its going into the parser, but its saying it is breaking out of the parse after .parseClaimsJws(token) line.)

this is my first post here so sorry that the formatting of the log dump is probably wrong but if someone wants to comment and tell me how to fix i will.

I have included some logging to watch as data gets passed along and see that the user and the token are being generated as they are supposed to and I believe that they are but I am really just learning spring and all its components. So if I have done everything else right inside my security bean classes then what could be the problem? i assume I'm missing some sort of metadata or maybe something in a property file disclosing the location of where to find existing tokens? I'm also wondering how the zuul security module will inheritly know what tokens were created by the other module when they aren't related other than through the @EnableZuulProxy in the gateway main?

here is creating a user(this method is from the users module):

```
@Override
    public UserDto createUser(UserDto userDetails) {
        log.info("creating user...{}",userDetails.toString());
        userDetails.setUserId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    userDetails.setEncryptedPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(userDetails.getPassword()));

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);

    UserEntity userEntity = modelMapper.map(userDetails, UserEntity.class);

    usersRepository.save(userEntity);
    UserDto returnValue = modelMapper.map(userEntity, UserDto.class);

    return returnValue;
}
```

create user log:

```
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.UsersServiceImpl - creating user...UserDto(firstName=FirstNameTest, lastName=LastNameTest, email=email@email.com, password=passwordTest, userId=null, encryptedPassword=null) 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.d.r.c.s.TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'save' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1254735951<open>)] for JPA transaction 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.TransactionImpl - On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.TransactionImpl - begin 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@2d8854a4] 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.b.CachedIntrospectionResults - Not strongly caching class [com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users.data.UserEntity] because it is not cache-safe 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.hibernate.SQL - call next value for hibernate_sequence 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.i.e.SequenceStructure - Sequence value obtained: 1 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.r.j.i.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl - HHH000387: ResultSet's statement was not registered 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractSaveEventListener - Generated identifier: 1, using strategy: org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1254735951<open>)] 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.e.t.i.TransactionImpl - committing 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Processing flush-time cascades 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Dirty checking collections 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 1 insertions, 0 updates, 0 deletions to 1 objects 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Flushed: 0 (re)creations, 0 updates, 0 removals to 0 collections 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.i.u.EntityPrinter - Listing entities: 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.h.i.u.EntityPrinter - com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users.data.UserEntity{firstName=FirstNameTest, lastName=LastNameTest, id=1, userId=5bc8d277-2b54-45e0-8419-fe220d6cf6ed, email=email@email.com, encryptedPassword=$2a$10$RlEUYpkZ..w2XHQfhCbQH.bpF84B2Cnq2CLLicV7MnEg1ZQd2.JGu} 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.hibernate.SQL - insert into users (email, encrypted_password, first_name, last_name, user_id, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.o.j.JpaTransactionManager - Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Using 'application/json', given [application/json] and supported [application/json] 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Writing [CreateUserResponseModel(firstName=FirstNameTest, lastName=LastNameTest, email=email@email.com, userI (truncated)...] 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.w.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@1ec98ba9 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-1] DEBUG o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet - Completed 201 CREATED
```

---

here is successful auth method from users module:

```
@Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {
        log.info("attempting authentication");
    try {
        log.info("reading input stream with object mapper.");
        LoginRequestModel creds = new ObjectMapper()
                .readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginRequestModel.class);
        log.info("creds email = {}",creds.getEmail());
        log.info("creds password = {}", creds.getPassword());

        log.info("calling getAuthenticationManager() from inside attemptAuthentication method");
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        creds.getEmail(),
                        creds.getPassword(),
                        new ArrayList<>()
                )
        );


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

}

@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response,
                                        FilterChain chain,
                                        Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
    log.info("AUTHENTICATION SUCCESS");

    String username = ((User) authResult.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
    log.info("creating token for user {}", username);

    UserDto userDetails = usersService.getUserDetailsByEmail(username);
    log.info("userid = {}",userDetails.getUserId());
    log.info("password = {}",userDetails.getPassword());
    log.info("email = {}",userDetails.getEmail());
    log.info("encrypted password = {}",userDetails.getEncryptedPassword());
    log.info("first name = {}",userDetails.getFirstName());
    log.info("last name = {}",userDetails.getLastName());

    log.info("creating token using jwts builder");

    String token = Jwts.builder()
            .setSubject(userDetails.getUserId())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + Long.parseLong(environment.getProperty("token.expiration_time"))))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, environment.getProperty("token.secret"))
            .compact();

    log.info("adding token to header: {}",token);
    log.info("adding userId to header: {}",userDetails.getUserId());

    response.addHeader("token", token);
    response.addHeader("userId", userDetails.getUserId());

}
```

and the log it produced:

```
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.AuthenticationFilter - attempting authentication 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.AuthenticationFilter - reading input stream with object mapper. 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.AuthenticationFilter - creds email = email@email.com 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.AuthenticationFilter - creds password = passwordTest 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.AuthenticationFilter - calling getAuthenticationManager() from inside attemptAuthentication method 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.a.ProviderManager - Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.UsersServiceImpl - loading user by username: email@email.com 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.o.j.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler - Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.q.c.i.CriteriaQueryImpl - Rendered criteria query -> select generatedAlias0 from UserEntity as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.email=:param0 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator - QueryTranslatorFactory : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory@1ac68724 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl - parse() - HQL: select generatedAlias0 from com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users.data.UserEntity as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.email=:param0 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.ErrorTracker - throwQueryException() : no errors 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl - --- HQL AST ---
 \-[QUERY] Node: 'query'
    +-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
    |  +-[FROM] Node: 'from'
    |  |  \-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
    |  |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'com'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'appsdeveloperblog'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'photoapp'
    |  |     |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'api'
    |  |     |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'users'
    |  |     |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'data'
    |  |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'UserEntity'
    |  |     \-[ALIAS] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
    |  \-[SELECT] Node: 'select'
    |     \-[IDENT] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
    \-[WHERE] Node: 'where'
       \-[EQ] Node: '='
          +-[DOT] Node: '.'
          |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
          |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'email'
          \-[COLON] Node: ':'
             \-[IDENT] Node: 'param0'
 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.HqlSqlBaseWalker - select << begin [level=1, statement=select] 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.t.FromElement - FromClause{level=1} : com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users.data.UserEntity (generatedAlias0) -> userentity0_ 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.t.FromReferenceNode - Resolved : generatedAlias0 -> userentity0_.id 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.t.FromReferenceNode - Resolved : generatedAlias0 -> userentity0_.id 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.t.DotNode - getDataType() : email -> org.hibernate.type.StringType@28a70766 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.t.FromReferenceNode - Resolved : generatedAlias0.email -> userentity0_.email 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.HqlSqlBaseWalker - select : finishing up [level=1, statement=select] 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.HqlSqlWalker - processQuery() :  ( SELECT ( {select clause} userentity0_.id ) ( FromClause{level=1} users userentity0_ ) ( where ( = ( userentity0_.email userentity0_.id email ) ? ) ) ) 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.u.JoinProcessor - Using FROM fragment [users userentity0_] 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.HqlSqlBaseWalker - select >> end [level=1, statement=select] 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl - --- SQL AST ---
 \-[SELECT] QueryNode: 'SELECT'  querySpaces (users)
    +-[SELECT_CLAUSE] SelectClause: '{select clause}'
    |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'userentity0_.id as id1_0_' {alias=generatedAlias0, className=com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users.data.UserEntity, tableAlias=userentity0_}
    |  \-[SQL_TOKEN] SqlFragment: 'userentity0_.email as email2_0_, userentity0_.encrypted_password as encrypte3_0_, userentity0_.first_name as first_na4_0_, userentity0_.last_name as last_nam5_0_, userentity0_.user_id as user_id6_0_'
    +-[FROM] FromClause: 'from' FromClause{level=1, fromElementCounter=1, fromElements=1, fromElementByClassAlias=[generatedAlias0], fromElementByTableAlias=[userentity0_], fromElementsByPath=[], collectionJoinFromElementsByPath=[], impliedElements=[]}
    |  \-[FROM_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'users userentity0_' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=generatedAlias0,role=null,tableName=users,tableAlias=userentity0_,origin=null,columns={,className=com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users.data.UserEntity}}
    \-[WHERE] SqlNode: 'where'
       \-[EQ] BinaryLogicOperatorNode: '='
          +-[DOT] DotNode: 'userentity0_.email' {propertyName=email,dereferenceType=PRIMITIVE,getPropertyPath=email,path=generatedAlias0.email,tableAlias=userentity0_,className=com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users.data.UserEntity,classAlias=generatedAlias0}
          |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'userentity0_.id' {alias=generatedAlias0, className=com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users.data.UserEntity, tableAlias=userentity0_}
          |  \-[IDENT] IdentNode: 'email' {originalText=email}
          \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=param0, expectedType=org.hibernate.type.StringType@28a70766}
 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.ErrorTracker - throwQueryException() : no errors 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl - HQL: select generatedAlias0 from com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users.data.UserEntity as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.email=:param0 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.QueryTranslatorImpl - SQL: select userentity0_.id as id1_0_, userentity0_.email as email2_0_, userentity0_.encrypted_password as encrypte3_0_, userentity0_.first_name as first_na4_0_, userentity0_.last_name as last_nam5_0_, userentity0_.user_id as user_id6_0_ from users userentity0_ where userentity0_.email=? 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.h.i.a.ErrorTracker - throwQueryException() : no errors 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.hibernate.SQL - select userentity0_.id as id1_0_, userentity0_.email as email2_0_, userentity0_.encrypted_password as encrypte3_0_, userentity0_.first_name as first_na4_0_, userentity0_.last_name as last_nam5_0_, userentity0_.user_id as user_id6_0_ from users userentity0_ where userentity0_.email=? 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.l.Loader - Result set row: 0 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.l.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users.data.UserEntity#1] 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.e.i.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users.data.UserEntity#1] 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.e.i.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users.data.UserEntity#1] 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.AuthenticationFilter - AUTHENTICATION SUCCESS 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.AuthenticationFilter - creating token for user email@email.com 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.o.j.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler - Creating new EntityManager for shared EntityManager invocation 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.q.c.i.CriteriaQueryImpl - Rendered criteria query -> select generatedAlias0 from UserEntity as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.email=:param0 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.hibernate.SQL - select userentity0_.id as id1_0_, userentity0_.email as email2_0_, userentity0_.encrypted_password as encrypte3_0_, userentity0_.first_name as first_na4_0_, userentity0_.last_name as last_nam5_0_, userentity0_.user_id as user_id6_0_ from users userentity0_ where userentity0_.email=? 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.l.Loader - Result set row: 0 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.l.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users.data.UserEntity#1] 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.e.i.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving associations for [com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users.data.UserEntity#1] 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.h.e.i.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [com.appsdeveloperblog.photoapp.api.users.data.UserEntity#1] 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.UsersServiceImpl - found user in database by email. name: email@email.com 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.AuthenticationFilter - userid = 5bc8d277-2b54-45e0-8419-fe220d6cf6ed 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.AuthenticationFilter - password = $2a$10$RlEUYpkZ..w2XHQfhCbQH.bpF84B2Cnq2CLLicV7MnEg1ZQd2.JGu 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.AuthenticationFilter - email = email@email.com 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.AuthenticationFilter - encrypted password = $2a$10$RlEUYpkZ..w2XHQfhCbQH.bpF84B2Cnq2CLLicV7MnEg1ZQd2.JGu 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.AuthenticationFilter - first name = FirstNameTest 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.AuthenticationFilter - last name = LastNameTest 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.AuthenticationFilter - creating token using jwts builder 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'token.expiration_time' in PropertySource 'applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]' with value of type String 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'token.secret' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.AuthenticationFilter - adding token to header: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1YmM4ZDI3Ny0yYjU0LTQ1ZTAtODQxOS1mZTIyMGQ2Y2Y2ZWQiLCJleHAiOjE1NjkwODc5MTF9.dGTH0D_ZdkGCWyU-1VsUW92299ZR5Udw_dySELVfpi-wUaXt1ZNWXfMhapVlVYNwqslTQ8pAi0ooB_AP61I6qw 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] INFO  c.a.p.a.u.s.AuthenticationFilter - adding userId to header: 5bc8d277-2b54-45e0-8419-fe220d6cf6ed 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.w.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@1ec98ba9 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession. 
[http-nio-auto-1-exec-2] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

---

-- my getAuth method from inside zuul gateway mmodule:

```
 private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.info("inside getAuthentication Method");
        log.info("requesting authentication path info from HttpServletRequest request path info = {}", request.getPathInfo());
        String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(environment.getProperty("authorization.token.header.name"));
        log.info("authorization header = {}", authorizationHeader);


    if (authorizationHeader == null) {
        log.info("authorization eader was null, returning.");
        return null;
    }

    String token = authorizationHeader.replace(environment.getProperty("authorization.token.header.prefix"),new String());
    log.info("stripped prefix from bearer token, left with {}", token);

    log.info("parsing token... if successful will be returned as userId");
    log.info("parsing using key: {}", (environment.getProperty("token.secret")));
    String userId = Jwts.parser()
            // might need to set here the type of token?
            /*the user class uses this:
            * .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, environment.getProperty("token.secret"))*/
            .setSigningKey(environment.getProperty("token.secret"))
            .parseClaimsJws(token)
            .getBody()
            .getSubject();

    log.info("parse successful! userId = {}" + userId);

    if (userId == null) {
        log.info("userId from http request was null!");
        return null;
    }
    log.info("returning userId = {}" + userId);

    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userId, null, new ArrayList<>());
}
```

}

-- heres the log it produced:

```
[http-nio-8011-exec-4] INFO  c.a.p.a.g.s.AuthorizationFilter - inside getAuthentication Method 
[http-nio-8011-exec-4] INFO  c.a.p.a.g.s.AuthorizationFilter - requesting authentication path info from HttpServletRequest request path info = null 
[http-nio-8011-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'authorization.token.header.name' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String 
[http-nio-8011-exec-4] INFO  c.a.p.a.g.s.AuthorizationFilter - authorization header = BearereyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1YmM4ZDI3Ny0yYjU0LTQ1ZTAtODQxOS1mZTIyMGQ2Y2Y2ZWQiLCJleHAiOjE1NjkwODc5MTF9.dGTH0D_ZdkGCWyU-1VsUW92299ZR5Udw_dySELVfpi-wUaXt1ZNWXfMhapVlVYNwqslTQ8pAi0ooB_AP61I6qw 
[http-nio-8011-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'authorization.token.header.prefix' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String 
[http-nio-8011-exec-4] INFO  c.a.p.a.g.s.AuthorizationFilter - stripped prefix from bearer token, left with eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1YmM4ZDI3Ny0yYjU0LTQ1ZTAtODQxOS1mZTIyMGQ2Y2Y2ZWQiLCJleHAiOjE1NjkwODc5MTF9.dGTH0D_ZdkGCWyU-1VsUW92299ZR5Udw_dySELVfpi-wUaXt1ZNWXfMhapVlVYNwqslTQ8pAi0ooB_AP61I6qw 
[http-nio-8011-exec-4] INFO  c.a.p.a.g.s.AuthorizationFilter - parsing token... if successful will be returned as userId 
[http-nio-8011-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'token.secret' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String 
[http-nio-8011-exec-4] INFO  c.a.p.a.g.s.AuthorizationFilter - parsing using key: 375892173452876 
[http-nio-8011-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver - Found key 'token.secret' in PropertySource 'configurationProperties' with value of type String 
[http-nio-8011-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.h.w.HstsHeaderWriter - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@3de0e6 
[http-nio-8011-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed 
[http-nio-8011-exec-4] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Filter execution threw an exception] with root cause
```

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter

---

application.properties for users module:

```
server.port=${PORT:0}
spring.application.name=users-ws
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka
spring.devtools.restart.enabled=true
eureka.instance.instance-id=${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test

gateway.ip=192.168.1.12
/TEN DAYS
token.expiration_time=864000000
token.secret=375892173452876
login.url.path=/users/login
```

---

application.properties for zuul module:

```
spring.application.name=zuul
server.port=8011
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8010/eureka
/Registration URL
api.registration.url-path=/users-ws/users
/Login URL
api.login.url-path=/users-ws/users/login
/H2 DB URL
api.h2-console.url-path=/users-ws/h2-console/**



authorization.token.header.name=Authorization

authorization.token.header.prefix=Bearer

token.secret=375892173452876
```

---

security config for zuul module:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurity(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(environment.getProperty("api.h2-console.url-path")).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, environment.getProperty("api.registration.url-path")).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, environment.getProperty("api.login.url-path")).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new AuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), environment));

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    }


}
```

I'd really love to allow users access to their own personal data that has been stored, but spring security won't recognize the bearer token i'm sending it!

Comment: You have not added SpringSecurityConfiguration Class content in your question

Comment: You might be having, classwhich configures SpringSecurity like 
```@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{
 @Override
 protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
 {
        http
        .addFilterBefore(myAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests() ... 
    }
    
}```

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi the form won't allow me to put anymore into it so thats all i can show u but i added the security config method from my zuul module.

Comment: I had doubt on your authenticate method where you are passing empty arraylist mean granted authority empty. But i am not sure, in your configuration you have not defined any role for any path but anyRequest().authenticated ...

Comment: Sorry, i didn't notice javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter

Comment: Logs not printing `log.info("parse successful! userId = {}" + userId);` and you have problem with Jwts.parser() right?

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi . i think my instructor said that the empty array in the arguments was just to defina a container for the email and password to be passed on with

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi yes you are correct log.info is not printing successfull parse

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi also the exception said something about a datatype converter class not found?

Comment: Cross check logs once again as there is no problem with your parser. Check logs completely for `parse successful! userId`

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi that is incorrect only parsing using key: 'key' is shown in log. that comes before the parse method. the program runs up to:  String userId = Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(environment.getProperty("token.secret"))
            .parseClaimsJws(token)

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi it doesnt crash there though, it goes internally into the framework and i get lost at that point. but somethign internally is throwing 403 and im getting classNotFoundException for the parser

Comment: you update question with complete logs

Comment: @PraveenKumarLalasangi sorry the form won't let me put any more code in im over the limit. maybe ud like to chat on discord or something

Answer (score 2):

fixed it!

after a day and a half of digging through debug logs and stack overflow i found out that the problem was i was getting a class not found exception on the parser. i learned that java se doesn't come with the nececary libraries to parse the token. it is standard only in java ee.

jave se users have to add this to their pom file.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```